# Displaying data containing more than one space in jqgrid in IE7

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

when displaying records retrieved from sql database in jqgrid in IE7, if data containing more than one space ,, it displays in jqrid only one space 
any idea to solve this problem ..

Answer (score 1):

In HTML when you have 2 spaces it will display as one, so there is special character for multiple spaces on one place `&nbsp;` or you can display your data in HTML tag `<pre>j   j</pre>`

So what you should do, replace all multiple spaces with "`&nbsp;`" or use **`<pre>`** to display it as it is.

Comment: As javascript's `s.replace(str, with)` replaces only single occurence of str, you may want to use regex for that `s.replace(/ /g, "&nbsp;")`